# Why am I getting a NullPointerException here?

Tags: java

```
Long n = null;
for (Long price : new Long[]{null, 2L, 10L}) {          
n = (n != null) ? 0L : price;   
}
```

I'm stumped, why am I getting a NPE when I execute this code ? 
Seems to be just a simple assignment of n = price where price is null.
Don't worry about what it means, it makes no sense.

Comment: this code makes totally no sense

Comment: Which line is the NPE being thrown?

Comment: This line, n = (n != null) ? 0L : price;

Comment: Should probably be: n = (price == null) ? 0L : price;

Comment: Is your intent to check to see if `price` is `null`?

Comment: ok whatever, n = (n == null) ? 0L : price; that throws an NPE too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the line `n = (n != null) ? 0L : price;`, you have a `long` and a `Long` as the alternatives to your `?:` statement. Java is going to construe this as of type `long` and will try to unbox the `Long`, instead of box the `long`. When `price` is null, as it is in the first iteration, this generates an NPE.

Answer (score 3):

This is because price is being unboxed to match the `0L` return possibility in the ternary operator.

Try instead:

```
Long n = null;
for (Long price : new Long[]{null, 2L, 10L}) {          
    n = (n != null) ? new Long(0L) : price;   
}
```

And all will run smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the byte code this happens

```
 49:    invokevirtual   #26; //Method java/lang/Long.longValue:()J
 52:    invokestatic    #20; //Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
```

when doing the comparison the `Long.longValue` is being executed on each item in that array causing your `NullPointerException`. The problem is that the ternary expression in combination with AutoBoxing is obscuring whats really occurring.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
n = (n != null) ? 0L : price;
```

gets compiled into

```
n = Long.valueOf(n == null ? price.longValue() : 0L);
```

The statement `price.longValue()` throws `NullPointerException` when `price` is `null`. Try replacing the array with `new Long[] {1L, 2L, 3L}` and see it work.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 n = (price != null) ? price : 0L;
```

Comment: You've changed the logic -- you're testing `price` not `n`.  Granted, this might be what the OP really wants, but it doesn't answer the question of why the NPE is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to coerce `price` to a primitive `long`, to match the type of `0L`.  This generates the NPE if `price` is `null`.

This expression works, because it avoids the implicit type coercion:

```
n = (n != null) ? new Long( 0L ) : price ;
```

But as others have said  in the comments, what you're doing here doesn't seem to make much sense anyway.